# Incorrect syntax near '.' in sql server table values function

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to join with table values function,
it gives me error this error:

**Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Line 2: Incorrect syntax near '.'.**

```
SELECT * from tbl t
inner join dbo.ufn_CSVToTable(t.text) a 
on t.text = a.String
```

What can be the error?

Comment: what is the meaning of "(t.text)" ?

Comment: Please post the code behind the function--can't help you otherwise.

Comment: text is the column name in table tbl.

Comment: function is fine i have checked this. if i execute the function like this SELECT * from dbo.ufn_CSVToTable('1,2,3') then it works fine but when i pass the column name as parameter then it gives error.

Comment: Is that a table valued function or a scalar function?

Comment: as i have mentioned that ufn_CSVToTable is table values function.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Incorrect syntax" using a table-valued function in SELECT clause of T-SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103624/incorrect-syntax-using-a-table-valued-function-in-select-clause-of-t-sql-query)

Answer (score 6):

1. You need CROSS or OUTER APPLY
2. You need to be on SQL Server 2005+
3. And **most** important, the [database compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) needs to be 90 or higher

Answer (score 3):

Try using `CROSS APPLY` instead of `JOIN`:

```
SELECT * from tbl t
CROSS APPLY dbo.ufn_CSVToTable(t.text) a 
WHERE t.text = a.String
```

Comment: error: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Line 2: Incorrect syntax near 'APPLY'.

Comment: Need to be compat level 90 or higher too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try being a bit more explicit -

```
SELECT * from tbl
inner join dbo.ufn_CSVToTable(tbl.text) a 
on tbl.text = a.String
```