# SQL Server : table-valued function does not work with sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, subquery, user-defined-functions

I have a SQL Server table-valued function which is created by me I have pasted the create script below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getTableFromString]
(       
    @String AS nvarchar(max)

)
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE ( StringValues nvarchar(10)  )   
AS begin 

    if (SELECT CHARINDEX(',', @String)) = 0
        begin
                insert into @ReturnTable (StringValues) values (subString(@String,1,len(@String)));
        end 
    else
        begin 
            while (SELECT CHARINDEX(',', @String)) > 0
            begin 
                insert into @ReturnTable (StringValues) values (subString(@String,1,CHARINDEX(',', @String)-1));
                set @String  = subString(@String,CHARINDEX(',', @String)+1,len(@String));

                if (SELECT CHARINDEX(',', @String)) = 0
                begin
                        insert into @ReturnTable (StringValues) values (subString(@String,1,len(@String)));
                end         
            end 
        end

    return ;
end
```

and I am using this function like below

```
Select sum(NetSales)
from vwxsalesall
where Company = 'rs'
and storecode = (select cPrimaryStockRoomCode from CompanyMaster.CompanyProfileDetail where cCompanyNo = 'rs' and cSecondaryStockRoomCode = 'R01B')
and trandate >= '2012-01-01'
and trandate <= '2012-01-31'
and ( 
        brand in (  
                    select StringValues from  dbo.getTableFromString(
                                                                    select vIncludedBrandCodes
                                                                    from StockRoomTargetData.MonthlyTarget 
                                                                    where cCompanyNo = 'rs' 
                                                                    and cSecondaryStockRoomCode = 'R01B'
                                                                    and nYear = 2012 
                                                                    and nMonth = 8
                                                                    )  
                 ) 
    )
```

Unfortunately I am getting this  error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

please help me

Comment: You need to put `select vIncludedBrandCodes ...` subquery into parenthesis to indicate to Sql Server that this is in fact a subquery.

Comment: Can you please explain little bit more please ?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another set of parenthesis around subquery, for instance

```
select StringValues from  dbo.getTableFromString(( { your-subquery }))

                                                 ^                  ^
                                                 (parenthesis added)
```

First set of parenthessis syntactically belong to TVF invocation, and second denote a subquery.

And now your query:

```
Select sum(NetSales)
from vwxsalesall
where Company = 'rs'
and storecode = (select cPrimaryStockRoomCode from CompanyMaster.CompanyProfileDetail where cCompanyNo = 'rs' and cSecondaryStockRoomCode = 'R01B')
and trandate >= '2012-01-01'
and trandate <= '2012-01-31'
and ( 
        brand in (  
                    select StringValues from  dbo.getTableFromString((
                                                                    select vIncludedBrandCodes
                                                                    from StockRoomTargetData.MonthlyTarget 
                                                                    where cCompanyNo = 'rs' 
                                                                    and cSecondaryStockRoomCode = 'R01B'
                                                                    and nYear = 2012 
                                                                    and nMonth = 8
                                                                    )) 
                 ) 
    )
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @Prabhakantha It works for me, [see it yourself](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1dc5/1). Which version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: @Prabhakantha Could you please post your current query if it is still not working?

Comment: i am using sql 2005 with compatibility level 80 and i cannot change the compatibility level in my database as some of the reports goes to not working state :'(

Comment: @Nicola I Just Pasted your query since you are using the same table names it should work for me :)

Comment: @Prabhakantha I cannot find inability to use subquery as a parameter in Sql Server 2000 mentioned anywhere. Could you try with simple example? `select StringValues from dbo.getTableFromString((select 'xyz'))`? If it is not working I'm afraid you will have to cross join subquery to main query and use `vIncludedBrandCodes` from there.

Comment: @Prabhakantha Please check [the answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103624/incorrect-syntax-using-a-table-valued-function-in-select-clause-of-t-sql-query). It seems that my proposed workaround will not work at all.

Comment: @Nicola you are correct select StringValues from dbo.getTableFromString((select 'xyz')) does not work's as well :) ... seems i have to find a work around for this :)  by the way thanks for the help :)  now i know its some thing to do with compatibility level :)

Comment: @Prabhakantha I'm sorry I could not help you more.