# Using a sql function inside a subquery with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, table-functions

I have the following query that works:

```
SELECT 
  STUFF
  (
    (
      SELECT
        ', ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(ulastname))
      FROM 
        ROOM r LEFT JOIN person p ON p.hmy = r.hmyperson
      WHERE 1=1 
        AND r.hmytenant = t.hmyperson
      FOR XML PATH('')
    )
  , 1 
  , 2 
  , ''
  )
FROM unit u
  LEFT JOIN tenant t ON u.hproperty = t.hproperty
WHERE 1=1
  AND t.hmyperson = 71
  AND u.hmy = 19
```

However, what I need to do is to use a function in the innermost select statement to return the proper values. I have written the query as follows:

```
SELECT 
  STUFF
  (
    (
      SELECT 
        ', ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(fullname))
      FROM 
        SMS_All_Occupants(u.hmy, 'Y', t.hmyperson) occ
      WHERE 1=1 
        AND TYPE = 'T' 
        AND LESSEE = 'Y'
      ORDER BY 
        occ.relation asc
      FOR XML PATH('')
    )
  , 1 
  , 2 
  , ''
  )
FROM unit u
  LEFT JOIN tenant t ON u.hproperty = t.hproperty
WHERE 1=1
  AND t.hmyperson = 71
  AND u.hmy = 19
```

This query always fails with "Incorrect syntax near '.'", which seems to have to do with the u.hmy and t.hmyperson being passed into the function.  If I put an actual value in for each of these paramaters it works as it should.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  I have seen references to using a cross join but I cannot figure out how to make the work.

Thanks!!

Comment: does the function work standalone? And what version of SQL Server?

Comment: The function does work standalone with hard-coded values and in a query window with declared variables, just not within a query and aliased columns.  Function works on multiple version of sql, currently testing on sql2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the DB Compatibility level still "80"? If so, you cannot use columns as UDF parameters

More here: ["Incorrect syntax" using a table-valued function in SELECT clause of T-SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5103624/27535)

Comment: That does seem to be the issue.  Thanks.  Now I have to see if I can change that on client machines or find another solution.